# gmailアドオンでメールの下書きを作成する場合の警告メッセージを変更したい

Tags: google-apps-script

[Class ComposeActionResponseBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/compose-action-response-builder)を利用してメールの下書きを作成する処理を実装しています。
下書きが存在する状態で 同様のアクションを行うと`A reply draft already exists.` というメッセージが表示されるのですが、日本語に変更したいです。
変更する方法はあるのでしょうか。

下記はメールの下書きを作成する処理です。

```
var keyValue = CardService.newKeyValue().setTopLabel("label").setContent("content").setMultiline(true)
    .setComposeAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('callCreateReplyDraft').setParameters({'hoge': 'hogehoge')})
    , CardService.ComposedEmailType.REPLY_AS_DRAFT);
section.addWidget(keyValue );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

下記日本語で表示されるようになってました。
`返信の下書きはすでにあります。`